# Tools which can parse Delphi XMLDoc format and build online help

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2007, delphi-2006

The XMLDoc tool for API documentation is explained here:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32770

Are there any free or commercial tools which can be used to create documentation based on Delphi's XML doc format?

Is there a newer version of the 'getting started' documentation? This page refers to Delphi 2005 and third party tools, some of them seem to have moved.

The XMLDoc for Delphi 2005 required

- Python (tested with Python 2.3)
- Instant Saxon (tested with Instant Saxon 6.5.3)
- The Java SDK (tested with J2SE v 1.4.2_05 SDK)
- and also the Visual Studio Help Integration Kit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:

- [Help and Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/)
- [HelpScribble](http://www.helpscribble.com/)
- [Doc-o-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/)

These tools should be able to create help files, and quite possibly also use XMLDoc as their input (both are Delphi-compatible or even written in Delphi).

Marc

Comment: Doc-o-Matic seems to be very interesting. I am still using doxygen (via pas2dox) - it works quite well, but has no support for new Delphi language features

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but if you want to use XMLDoc for your Delphi code, I strongly recommend this [open tool plug-in from CodeCentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23153). I just tested it in Delphi 2010, and it still works fine.