# Is comments needed for BizTalk Custom Pipeline Component?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-pipelines

I'm newbie to BizTalk Custom Pipeline Component. I mean by 'comments' is adding lines like below in pipeline component.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads configuration properties for the component
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyBag">Configuration property bag</param>
    /// <param name="errorLog">Error status</param>
    public virtual void Load(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPropertyBag propertyBag, int errorLog)
    { Code goes here }
```

What is the use of this /// < summary> and all? Is this really needed to build custom pipeline component?

Comment: That style comment is used to generate XMLDoc documentation for code. It's needed unless you're willing to write your own documentation manually.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830330/62576) for an example of documenting Delphi code using XMLDoc notation.